# With Apache Camel, how to add some lines to an already big file?

Tags: java, apache-camel, large-files

I have a process actually with 3 steps :

1. reformat a csv to another format (using split&aggregator)
2. manually add some lines as header & footer
3. zip & send to ftp

All that is working correctly when testing, but later, i saw that the step 2 fails when big CSVs are given to process.

**Details about that step 2**

Route for step 2 & 3

```
      <route id="tozip">
        <from uri="file:{{path}}/out?readLock=changed"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>resource:file:{{path}}/conf/HeadTxtFoot.txt</simple>
        </setBody>
         <log message="Compressing message..." loggingLevel="INFO" />
         <marshal ref="gzip" />
         <log message="Sending ${file:name}.gz..." loggingLevel="INFO" />
         <to uri="file:{{path}}/tosend/?fileName=${file:name}.gz" />
      </route>
```

HeadTxtFoot.txt

```
<tag>
    <informationDate>${headers.date}</informationDate>
    <files>
    ${body}
    </files>
<tag>
```

I had recently a file of 350Mb entering in this route, and i have this error

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[tozip             ] [tozip             ] [file:///u01?readLock=changed                 ] [       459]
[tozip             ] [setBody2          ] [setBody[simple{resource:file:{{path}}/conf/HeadTxtFoot.txt}]                  ] [       459]

Stacktrace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.String with value [Body is file based: GenericFile[/u01/file.xml]] due java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:667)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:158)
...
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:1410)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.StaticMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(StaticMethodTypeConverter.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:326)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:141)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The same route without the setBody/Simple works OK

Now, my question is : what is the best way to add the lines in the file avoiding the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are reading the whole file into java memory, so that it's then running out of memory giving you the Java heap space issue.

To fix: don't read the whole file into memory. Instead use "streams" to stream the file contents. To do this you can set the streaming parameter on your route